# Sed - remove first occurence of string from file

Tags: perl, sed

I have a file called test.txt which contains the following:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test3
```

I am using the following code to remove `"test3"` from the file:

```
sed -i '/test3/d' test.txt
```

However I only want to remove only the first occurrence of `"test3"`

Comment: Add a one time use variable and a conditional, such as `$a++ || ...`

Comment: Why does this question have a Perl tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sed one-liner will help you:

```
sed '0,/test3/{/test3/d}' file
test1
test2
test4
test5
test3
```

This sed command has used sed's address. Sed has different address expressions, this was explained in detail in sed's Info page.

For this command, `0, /pattern/` will focus from the first line till the first line matching `/pattern/`, then do the action: `/pattern/d`, that is, remove the first matching line. After this was done, all following lines will not be satisfied with address `0,/pattern/`, thus default action was taken: print as they are.

Comment: Why don't you add an explanation for this code you are presenting so that someone might learn from it.

Comment: @TLP explanation was added. Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Please add hyperlinks for *"has used sed's address"* and *"sed's Info page"*

Comment: @Kent: I know that, but suppose I had only a WIndows system to hand?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (not as good as Kent's I think) to rely on the hold space:

```
sed -e '/test3/{
                x
                /^$/d
               }'
```

This looks for the pattern, then if it sees it it exchanges it with the hold space which will be empty on the first hit, and then nukes the remaining blank line.  For subsequent hits the hold space will contain the line itself, swapped in by the first hit, so the exchange will do nothing, and the blank-line-nuking will fail.

I think, however, the real answer is don't use `sed`: I almost always find it easier to use Perl, or almost anything else, when things get complicated enough to need any thought.

Comment: Your explanation of why this works only makes partial sense, however the method is sound.

Comment: @potong: I've elaborated the explanation a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl

```
 perl -pe 'next if /test3/ and not $seen++' test.txt
```

Comment: `print() ` is in `continue{ }` for `-p` switch, so $_="" instead of `next`

Answer (score 0):

Another Perl sledgehammer way

```
perl -0777 -p's/text3\n//' test.txt
```