# How to remove n lines in a log file only after the first match of the pattern

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a log file which contains several repeats of the pattern `Fre --`. I need to remove only first occurrence of this pattern and the next 20 lines after that and keep other matches intact. I need to do it in a bash terminal, using `sed` preferably or `awk` or `perl`. I would highly appreciate your help.

I tried

```
sed -e '/Fre --/,+20d' log.log
```

but it deletes all the patterns and next 20 lines after that. I want only first pattern to be removed

There is a more or less similar question and some answers here: [How to remove only the first occurrence of a line in a file using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696871/how-to-remove-only-the-first-occurrence-of-a-line-in-a-file-using-sed) but I don't know how to change it to remove 20 lines after the first match

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700633/sed-remove-first-occurence-of-string-from-file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396974/sed-or-awk-delete-n-lines-following-a-pattern

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: I tried sed -e '/Fre --/,+20d' log.log but it deletes all the patterns and next 20 lines after that. I want only first pattern to be removed

Comment: there is a more or less similar question and some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696871/how-to-remove-only-the-first-occurrence-of-a-line-in-a-file-using-sed
but I don't know how to change it to remove 20 lines after the first match

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output. Use, say, 5 as your line count rather than 20 to minimize the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure that someone will find a nice `sed` command but I know `awk` better.

You can try :

```
awk '/Fre --/ && !found++{counter=21}--counter<0' log.log
```

Explanations :

`/Fre --/` -> if it finds pattern `Fre --`

`&& !found++` -> and if it didn't find it before

`{counter=21}` -> it sets counter value at 21 (because you want to remove the line + the next 20s)

`--counter<0` -> decreases the counter and prints the line only if counter < 0

As mentioned by @Sundeep, @EdMorton solution is safer on very big files.

```
awk '/Fre --/ && !found++{counter=21}!(counter&&counter--)' log.log
```

**NOTE**

If you want the deletions to be saved into the original file, you will have to copy the contents of the `awk` command into a temp file, and then move the temp file into the original file. Always be careful before editing the original file since you may lose precious informations.

Run the first command first :

```
awk '/Fre --/ && !found++{counter=21}!(counter&&counter--)' log.log > log.log.tmp
```

Then check the .tmp file and you can run the second command to apply the changes if .tmp file looks ok :

```
mv log.log.tmp log.log
```

Comment: With `GNU sed`, it would be something like `sed '0,/Fre --/{//{N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d}}'` .. `awk` is better suited here.. one thing though, your counter could cause issue if the input file is large enough due to finite precision

Comment: There may be a sed command but it definitely won't be nice :-).

Comment: @EdMorton @Sundeep > I tried to combine those two commands and couldn't find a way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700633/sed-remove-first-occurence-of-string-from-file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396974/sed-or-awk-delete-n-lines-following-a-pattern . Something like `sed '0,/test3/{/test3/+3d}' file` . I'm surprised that such a solution does not exist.

Comment: Thanks @RaphaelSetin for adding the info on how to actually delete the lines on the original file. I updated a bit your suggestions since I prefer to avoid showing commands that could delete information on original files on stackoverflow. Developers sometimes copy/paste commands and could lose precious informations.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ seq 20 | awk '!f && /3/{c=4; f=1} !(c&&c--)'
1
2
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

See [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105)

Comment: I was trying something similar from that Q&A (I've bookmarked the link)... I got `awk 'c&&c--{next} /3/&&!f{f=1; c=3; next} 1'` before seeing your optimized version

Comment: It could be made slightly more brief too as `awk '/3/&&!f++{c=4}!(c&&c--)'` but we're trading off clarity a bit too much now IMHO!

Comment: @AminAlibakhshi safer solution than mine on big files